# How to restore SQL Server database by backup description?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I make a description when a create backup.

I can retrieve information about my backups:

```
SELECT name, database_name, description, backup_start_date FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
```

Can I restore database by script, using description and/or backup created date?

I need something like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM  DISK = N'D:\dbbackups\ByDB.bak'
Where Description = 'SomeDescr' and Date = '10.05.2016'
```

Comment: I do not think that you can, see syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found one way

```
declare @Position int = 0;

SELECT @Position = position
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name = 'MyDB'
and type = 'I' and Description = 'some description'

print @Position

ALTER DATABASE [myDB] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE


RESTORE DATABASE [myDB] FROM  DISK = N'D:\dbbackups\myDB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
RESTORE DATABASE [myDB] FROM  DISK = N'D:\dbbackups\myDB.bak' WITH  FILE = @Position,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```